# What determines NSTask default PATH - and why does it differ from Terminal

Tags: macos, cocoa

I was attempting to execute a command line tool (BBEdit’s “bbdiff”) from a NSTask /bin/sh launched from a Cocoa program.

This failed, even though I could successfully launch from Terminal.

I tracked down the cause; `bbdiff` is in `/usr/local/bin`.

The PATH used in Terminal is

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

However the PATH used in a bash shell launched by NSTask is only

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Why the difference? I thought `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` was the normal path used by UNIX

Comment: This is probably undefined.  Best to test for the binary you want to run and execute it using the full path.

Answer (score 0):

As the NSTask docs say (emphasis added):

> A task operates within an environment defined by the current values
>   for several items: the current directory, standard input, standard
>   output, standard error, and the values of any **environment variables**.
>   By default, an NSTask object inherits its environment from the process
>   that launches it.

So your NSTask gets the PATH used to launch your Cocoa app.

Comment: This just moves the question back one step. I launch from Taskbar. I also launch Terminal from Taskbar, but the PATH are different. So what environment does the Taskbar inherit.

Comment: At the risk of seeming obvious, it inherits an environment where `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`  :-)